# My metadata is devoid of the summary comments. What is the procedure to insert the summary of each functions within the metadata?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments, metadata, summary

I have created a library file (dll) in C# (using VS 2012) with a list of functions within it. Most of the functions have been properly commented using the summary comments. Now when I use these library functions in a separate project and do a 'Go to Definition' it navigates me to the metadata which is absolutely fine. However, the metadata contains only the function declaration. It is completely devoid of any description as is usually found. Is there a separate procedure to ensure the metadata contains the function summaries as well?

Comment: add xml comment on each function

Comment: Hi Pranay,

This is what I'm doing already...I am getting the XML documentation file as well...however my question is how to show the same in the metadata....for some reason only the function declaration is being shown if I choose to go to definition or hover the mouse on the selected function, but not the entire summary

Comment: I just figured out that XML documentation itself is sufficient enough to get the task done...the problem I was facing was due to the fact that the source for the class library and my main project are in the same solution...so the metadata was showing just the function declaration. Once I used the compiled dll in a separate project by just adding it as the reference, the metadata showed both the function declaration as well as the summary. I guess Microsoft developed it the smart way and chose not to show the summary as the source code for the class library also resided in the same solution.